# Redirect To Specific URL in Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, gql

I am working in google app engine , 
i want to redirect browser to the specific URL which is retrived from Datastore.

The model of stored URL is like,

```
class WebReference(db.Model):
    website = db.StringProperty()
    webreferecnce=db.StringProperty()
```

My code is ,

```
query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM WebReference where webreferecnce = '10'")
            results = query.fetch(1)
            for r in results:
                self.redirect(r.website)
```

I want to redirect the URL to the website who have webreference number 10.
This is running at localhost but not after uploading.
how can i achieve this ?

Comment: What does the app-engine log say about that request? (you can see it at https://appengine.google.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one , this is worked for me, dont forget to convert url in string like str(YourURLgoesHere)

```
result = WebReference.gql("WHERE webreferecnce= :1", parameter)
    for record in result.run(limit=1):
        self.redirect(str(record.website))
```

Answer (score 0):

You select where r.webreferecnce = '10' and then you redirect to the value of the field webreferecnce, which will be 10. Maybe you mean something like

self.redirect(r.website), if that's where your URL is stored.
Basically, think through what you actually want to do.

Comment: Sorry , that was my typing mistake it is actually `self.redirect(r.website)`

Comment: OK. So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is that it is not going to redirected to specific URL